# show that it is a Banach space

Tags: general-topology

consider $(X, \| \|)$  Banach space, prove that $\ (X × X, \| \|_0) $ where $ \| \ (x, y) \|_0 = \max \ (\|x\|, \|y\|)$ is a Banach space.

Solución:

if ${(x_n, y_n) }$  is Cauchy then for all $ϵ> 0$  there exists $ N∈N$ such that for all $m, n $ greater than $N$  is $\| \ (x_m − x_n, y_m − y_n) \|_0 = \max \ {\|x_m− x_n\|, \| 
  \| y_m − y_n∥} <ϵ.$ Since both $ \|x_m − x_n\| $ and $ \|y_m − y_n\|$ are less than
$\max \ {∥\|x_m − x_n\|, \|y_m − y_n\|} <ϵ$ since you already have that both sequences are Cauchy.

is this proof correct? there is nothing more to add?

Comment: it's OK for me. Just end by explaining that there is a pair (x,y) to which the Cauchy sequence converges.

Comment: Can you tell me how this part demonstrates what you tell me? thanks for answering. I actually thought that was enough.

Comment: You need more explanation, as usual.

Comment: I think it is common, I am learning, I do not know everything, I send what I have been able to do and when I cannot, I ask for help. This is new for me.

Comment: In a complete space all the Cauchy sequences converge. It is assumed that in step 1) I have shown that the sequences $ x_n$  and $ y_n $ are Cauchy, and as the statement says that we are in a Banach space (which means complete and normed) then both sequences converge., As is it shown that both converge? I really ask why I don't know, I'm stuck here friends.

Comment: @angelabayona what you did is ok, I would just say to conclude that as the sequence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $X$, there is its limit, let's say $x$, the same thing for the sequence $(y_n)$, let's say it has a limit $y$. Hence I claim that $(x,y)$ is the limit of $(x_n , y_n)$ in the product space, but this is of course true by the definition of the norm in the product space. Therefore, the product space is Banach.